# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut pause on hover

Tags: hover, fadein, fadeout

I have a little jQuery snippet that will fadeIn and fadeOut a group of divs over a select interval.  I now need to pause this fadeIn fadeOut on hover, then resume on mouse out.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is the relevant code.

The following is what is located in my body

```
<div class="gcRotate">
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px;">
            This is first content
            <img src="http://pix.motivatedphotos.com/2008/6/16/633492359109161542-Skills.jpg"
               alt="Dude" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is second content
            <img src="http://www.funnycorner.net/funny-pictures/5010/cheezburger-locats.jpg"
               alt="Dude" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is third content
            <img src="http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/business.jpg" alt="Dude" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      This shouldn't move.
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function fadeContent() {

         $(".gcRotate .gcRotateContent:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function() {
         $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());

            fadeContent();
         });
      }

      $(".gcRotate").height(0);

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(
         function() {
            if ($(".gcRotate").height() < $(this).height()) {
               $(".gcRotate").height($(this).height());
            }
         }
         );

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(function() {
         $(this).css("display", "none")
      });

      fadeContent();


   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out on my own.

```
<div class="gcRotate">
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px;">
            This is first content
            <img src="http://pix.motivatedphotos.com/2008/6/16/633492359109161542-Skills.jpg"
               alt="First" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is second content
            <img src="http://www.funnycorner.net/funny-pictures/5010/cheezburger-locats.jpg"
               alt="Second" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gcRotateContent">
         <div style="border: solid 2px black; text-align: center; width: 150px">
            This is third content
            <img src="http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2007/06/business.jpg" alt="Third" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      This shouldn't move.
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function fadeContent() {

         $(".gcRotateContent").first().fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".gcRotateContent:hidden:first").fadeIn(500)
         });
         $(".gcRotateContent").first().appendTo($(".gcRotateContent").parent());
      }

      $(".gcRotate").height(0);

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(
         function() {
            if ($(".gcRotate").height() < $(this).height()) {
               $(".gcRotate").height($(this).height());
            }
         }
         );

      $(".gcRotateContent").each(function() {
         $(this).css("display", "none")
      });

      $(".gcRotate").hover(function() {window.clearInterval(timer)}, function() {timer = window.setInterval("fadeContent()", 2000)});

      $(".gcRotateContent").first().show(0);
      var timer = window.setInterval("fadeContent()", 2000);


   </script>
```